# Mobile menu navigation not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, response, mobile-website

I am working on this website http://www.onlineshoppingdeals.in/

The menu works fine (redirection to the right links) if you open in the desktop browser.

Redirection fails if it open in the mobile browser. Whats wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I checked the website and saw that when  `width > 768` the links are in `<a>` tags but when you convert it to mobile (`width < 768`) the nav become a `<select>` tag with `<options>` in it. So you need to write some JavaScript code which will be firing itself with `$('select').change()`

Comment: Dont know but the problem is what i told. Your navigation changes from <ul> to <select> totally different elements.

Comment: could you also please tell me why there is no arrow icon in the mobile view?

Comment: What do yo mean with arrow icon? I Cannot see any arrow on this website. Did you buy it or built it yourself? Its sounds like you bought it.

Answer (score 1):

There is two way to do it, bootstrap using two menus hide and show them as per media queries.

1. Easy method is

   http://www.foo.bar'" >Foo
       http://www.foo.bar'">Bar
2. Hard method is

[enter image description here][1]

you can delete mini menu continue using main menu as per below image. you just need to change the menu icon.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S87kS.jpg)

Comment: could you also please tell me why there is no arrow icon in the mobile view?

Comment: It seems your **glyphicons** is missing. simply copy and paste **fonts** folder on website root it will appear automatically.